# MarkLogic CoRB Error - com.marklogic.developer.corb.ModuleExecutor main INFO: processing error - exiting with code 2

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

We are running a CoRB job with below settings, but its failing.

**Settings:**

- App Server: HTTP Server
- CoRB Version: 2.4.3

Properties File:

```
XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xccs://username:password@Load Balancer URL:port/dbname 
THREAD-COUNT=2 
ERROR-FILE-NAME=/path/example.out 
FAIL-ON-ERROR=false 
MODULES-DATABASE=modules_dbname 
MODULE-ROOT=/path/ 
PROCESS-MODULE=process_modules_example.xqy 
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask 
COMMAND-FILE=/path/CoRB/examplecommand.properties 
SSL-CONFIG-CLASS=com.marklogic.developer.corb.TrustAnyoneSSLConfig 
SSL-ENABLED-PROTOCOLS=TLSv1.2
```

**Error:**

> SEVERE: Error while running CORB
> com.marklogic.developer.corb.CorbException: ContentSource not available.
> at com.marklogic.developer.corb.DefaultContentSourcePool.get(DefaultContentSourcePool.java:117)
> at com.marklogic.developer.corb.ModuleExecutor.run(ModuleExecutor.java:206)
> at com.marklogic.developer.corb.ModuleExecutor.main(ModuleExecutor.java:87)

> Dec 07, 2023 1:18:58 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.ModuleExecutor main
> INFO: processing error - exiting with code 2

*Note:* We've tried by enabling and disabling below 2 parameters from the properties file, but still no luck.

```
SSL-CONFIG-CLASS=com.marklogic.developer.corb.TrustAnyoneSSLConfig
SSL-ENABLED-PROTOCOLS=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Also, PFB properties file related to the above issue for reference.

**Properties File:**

XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xccs://username:password@Load Balancer URL:port/dbname
THREAD-COUNT=2
ERROR-FILE-NAME=/path/example.out
FAIL-ON-ERROR=false
MODULES-DATABASE=modules_dbname
MODULE-ROOT=/path/
PROCESS-MODULE=process_modules_example.xqy
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
COMMAND-FILE=/path/CoRB/examplecommand.properties
SSL-CONFIG-CLASS=com.marklogic.developer.corb.TrustAnyoneSSLConfig
SSL-ENABLED-PROTOCOLS=TLSv1.2

Comment: You are pointing CoRB at an HTTP appserver or an XDBC appserver? CoRB uses XCC, so need an XDBC appserver (or hybrid, like App-Services port 8000). CoRB 2.4.3 is an older version, there were changes in v2.5.0 to make TLS 1.2 the default (and configurable). If you need TLS 1.2, try upgrading to the latest version v2.5.6 and retry.

Comment: Since you are going through a load balancer, the `xcc.httpcompliant` flag needs to be set. CoRB does that automatically for you since v2.5.1 - another reason to upgrade.

Comment: Mads, I am using HTTP app server and let me see by upgrading the CoRB to 2.5.0 version. Also, will try enabling the xcc.httpcompliant=true. Earlier using older protocols, we use to run the CoRB on same HTTP app server without any issues and now we are using TLS1.2 version.

Comment: @MadsHansen - After upgrading the CoRB to 2.5.6, the job is succeeding with TLS 1.2 version. The issue is resolved. Thanks for the guidance.